# PHP merge array issues

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array as such

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => PrettyName1
        [1] => PrettyName2
        [2] => PrettyName3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => UglyURL1
        [1] => UglyURL2
        [2] => UglyURL3
    )

)
```

I want to be able to put these into an array for a code-igniter template, well when I push and merge arrays I end up messing the whole thing up. Can someone show me the proper way to merge these arrays? I need something like

```
Array
(
    PrettyName1 => UglyURL1
    PrettyName2 => UglyURL2
    PrettyName3 => UglyURL3
)
```

Comment: This representation is not possible. Do you mean `Array (PrettyName1 => UglyURL1, PrettyName2 => UglyURL2, PrettyName3 => UglyURL3)` ?

Comment: You should build the array as you expect to use it later on.

Comment: Do you know the size of the array? or is it random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this `array_combine($ar[1], $ar[2])` ?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for this! I had no clue such function existed, makes this a WHOLE lot simpler! I'll accept your answer once it allows me.

Comment: @Robby Duke, PHP has thousands of functions. Learn them and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).